# How do I find out which application is disabling sleep?

Tags: xfce, power-management, suspend, sleep

Sometimes when I try to suspend my laptop (using the sleep keyboard button), I get this popup from xfce4-power-manager: `"Are you sure you want to hibernate the system? An application is currently disabling the automatic sleep. Doing this action now may damage the working state of this application."`  I don't want to hibernate - I would like to know **which** application is disabling sleep, so that I can quit it and suspend the system normally.  How can I find this out?

I'm on Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Please don't cross post between sites. http://askubuntu.com/questions/824583/how-do-i-find-out-which-application-is-disabling-sleep

Comment: Deleted cross-post, sorry. (I do wish here and askubuntu weren't confusingly separate.)

Comment: Newer versions of xfce4-power-manager have this information in tray menu.

Comment: @PF4Public Running XUbuntu 18.04 but I don't see this... where exactly should it be showing up?

Comment: @Wil See this screenshot: https://imgur.com/TVkO2GC

Comment: @PF4Public ty, but for some reason I'm not seeing that on XUbuntu 18.04's stock install of xfce4's power manager applet.  I have both the tray enabled and the plugin side-by-side, neither is showing it. :-(

Comment: @Wil That probably suggests to be another question as it would be really hard to guess what's wrong with your install in comments section here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under Freedesktop-compliant environments, including XFCE4, sleep inhibition is communicated via D-Bus on the `org.freedesktop.PowerManagement` bus. I can't find any documentation about this; the xfce4 code has a [list of methods](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/xfce/power-manager/src/org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.xml) which includes one called `GetInhibitors` so this should work:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.GetInhibitors
```

Comment: how to I politely tell the system to ignore the request to prevent suspending, since by preventing suspending, these applications are realizing their own worst nightmare - powerfail - instead of allowing the system to sleep and preserve their consistency when the battery hits 10%.

Comment: @Wil I don't know. Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: ty, done : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448702/how-to-prevent-applications-from-causing-powerfail-when-power-management-is-conf

Comment: Using this command I found it was Chrome browser, and specifically a single tab (website) the one blocking the hibernation. Closing that Tab/Web solved the problem.