# How to prevent applications from causing Powerfail when power management is configured to suspend at 10% battery

Tags: xfce, power-management, suspend, d-bus

When my laptop attempts to suspend itself to avoid powerfail, instead of successfully suspending, I get a popup from xfce4-power-manager: "Are you sure you want to hibernate the system? An application is currently disabling the automatic sleep. Doing this action now may damage the working state of this application."

How do I prevent applications from preventing suspend when battery is low?

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.PowerManagement /org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.GetInhibitors
```

reveals:

> freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit
>   org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.GetInhibitors method return
>   time=1528483300.093042 sender=:1.35 -> destination=:1.96 serial=81
>   reply_serial=2    array [
>         string "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"    ]

but sometimes there are others too.

Needless to say this is disastrous to my laptop's state of charge and battery health and results in recoverable filesystem corruption when these apps idiotically force the system to powerfail by prematurely depleting the battery and then preventing the life-saving suspend that would have prevented them losing state.

Ideally some of these applications should still be able to prevent suspend when the system is not low on battery, but I'd like be given an opportunity to *permit* that behaviour.  It should *never* have been made a default setting that applications can overcome power management settings which are in place to protect the hardware and filesystem consistency!

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1775921

Comment: (ok removed the comment)